# How to callbacks Serial Dispatch Queues in GCD

Tags: iphone

```
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue=dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", nil);
dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
    printf("Do some work here.\n");
});
dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^{
    printf("Do Some Things here!!!\n");
});
```

I implemented Serial Dispatch Queues,I assigned two task after that i want to callback a task that notify the whole application.How do this?.

Comment: So you want to notify the task after the threads are startet or when they have finished?

Comment: You can stick something on the main queue when all your tasks have finished.  Read the man page for dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: yes   Claus Bönnhoff